# Gradle error while running my flutter application

Tags: entity-framework, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I cloned a flutter project but i can't be able to run on my device. I this is error that kept on show-facing please can I handle it. Meanwhile I've ran **flutter pub get**

[image]

Please here is the stack tree:

```
C:\Users\EazybankCoreAPI\Documents\flutterprojects\FlutterEbookApp>flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on GIONEE F205 in debug mode...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)       
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)       
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)       
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        28.2s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)       
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         0.3s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: You have an error while downloading files, are you connected to the internet? Is Flutter correctly installed? Lots of questions that only you can answer. Also next time please post the stacktrace instead of a screenshot. Nobody can copy anything from a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device is connected well to internet if you use API,

If you not, please restart VSCode